# Using PDO PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Alright peeps, This is my first question on stack overflow and it should be a easy one at that but since I cannot figure out what the right words for what I am trying to do its making it incredibly difficult for me to search it.

I am using PDO for my DB connection.

Anyways, I am trying to query the database and then set `$fname` to a string, I know how to set it to an array like this `while ($fname = $name->fetch()){}` but *how can I simply set `$fname` to a string instead?*

The snippet of code and a link to where I can read more about it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
while ($fname = $name->fetch())
{
echo "{$fname['fieldName']}";
}
```

Comment: You got it! Thank you. The curly brackets was what I needed, why?